# nested function in python (taking the output from another function)

Tags: python, function

I have problem with getting output from another function to use in a function.
I don't know the syntax of function in python. How do i take a output of another function to use in a function when i define it.
def hero_attribute(hero_selection()): #This syntax isn't accepted

```
#This program will calculate the damge of hero with stats
global hero_str_result
global hero_agi_result
global hero_int_result

def hero_selection():
    print """1. Life Stealer (strength hero)\n
    2. Phantom lancer (agility hero)\n
    3. Phantom Assassin (agility hero)\n
    4. Wrait King (strength hero) \n
    """

    print "Please enter hero selection: "
    hero_num = int(raw_input("> "))
    return hero_num

def hero_attribute(hero_selection()): #This syntax isn't accepted 
    if hero_num == 1: # Life stealer 
        hero_str = 25 
        hero_agi = 18 
        hero_int = 15 
        #Hero growth stats
        str_growth = 2.4 
        agi_growth = 1.9 
        int_growth = 1.75 

    elif hero_num == 2: # Phantom lancer 
        hero_str = 
        hero_agi = ?
        hero_int = ?
        #Hero growth stats
        str_growth = 2.4
        agi_growth = 1.9
        int_growth = 1.75

    elif hero_num == 3: # Phantom Assassin
        hero_str = ?
        hero_agi = ?
        hero_int = ?
        #Hero growth stats
    else: #Wraith King
        hero_str = ?
        hero_agi = ?
        hero_int = ?    
        #hero growth stats
        str_growth = ?
        agi_growth = ?
        int_growth = ?  
    return (hero_str,hero_agi,hero_int,str_growth,agi_growth,int_growth)

def hero_type(hero_num):
    if hero_num == 1:
        hero_type = "str"
    elif hero_num == 2
        hero_type = "agi"
    elif hero_num == 3
        hero_type = "agi"   
    else:
        hero_type = "str"


#the function will ask user what to do with the hero
def hero_build():
    print "What do you want to do with the hero?"
    print """1. Build hero with stat
        2. Build hero with item (not yet)
        3. Build hero with level
        """

    user_choice = int(raw_input("> "))
    if user_choice == 1:
        print "You want to build hero with stats!"
        print "Please enter number of stats that you want to add: "
        hero_stats = int(raw_input=("> "))

        hero_str, hero_agi, hero_int,str_growth,agi_growth,int_growth = hero_attribute() #This function will take the result of hero_str, hero_agi,hero_int
        hero_str_result = hero_str + str_growth * hero_stats
        hero_agi_result = hero_agi + agi_growth * hero_stats
        hero_int_result = hero_int + int_growth * hero_stats    


    return hero_str_result, hero_agi_result, hero_int_result


print "This is the result of your build: ", hero_build()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function is a piece of code that receive **arguments**, and to those arguments you assign a name. For example:

```
def square(x):
    return x * x
```

this function computes the square of a number; this unknown number in the body of the function will be called `x`.

Once you have a function you can **call** it, passing the values you want as arguments... for example

```
print( square(12) )
```

will print `144` because it will call the function `square` passing `x=12` and `12*12` is `144`.

You can of course pass a function the **result of calling another function**, e.g.

```
def three_times(x):
    return 3 * x

print( square( three_times(5) ) )
```

will display 225 because the function `three_times` will be passed 5 and it will return `3*5`, the function `square` will be passed `15` and will return `15*15`.

In the **function definition** (the `def` part) you will always just have **names** for the parameters. What you want to pass to the function will be written at the **call site**.

Comment: This more a comment on the OP's question statement rather than on your answer: The question seemed to me about the function declaration & definition, while your answer is about function composition. Can one include a _function call_ (as opposed to just a function) in the declaration of a function? Anyway, the OP accepted it, so I guess function composition  was what (s)he was looking for. Some questions are really confusing.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to be able to pass a function as argument. This, however, is already incorporated into python from design: you simply pass it as you pass any other argument.

Example:

```
def apply(f,x):
   return f(x)
def sq(x):
   return x*x
def cb(x):
   return x*x*x
apply(sq,2)
4
apply(cb,2)
8
```

Apply is defined with its first argument being a function. You know that only when you actually read the definition of `apply`. There you see that `f` is treated as a function, as opposed to x which is treated "as a number".